# Nontrivial Signed Measure on Lebesgue Measurable Sets Being Trivial on Borel Sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

Let $\mathfrak{L}(\mathbb{R})$ be the collection of Lebesgue measurable sets and $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ be the Borel sets.

**Question:** Is there a nontrivial **signed** measure on $\mathfrak{L}(\mathbb{R})$ that is trivial on $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

Obviously, any **positive** measure that is trivial on $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is also trivial on $\mathfrak{L}(\mathbb{R})$, since any Lebesgue measurable set is a subset of a Borel set.

For the signed case, I have tried doing Jordan decomposition but it doesn't seem work. It is hard (if ever possible) to show $(\mu|_{\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})})^+ = \mu^+|_{\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})}$ and $(\mu|_{\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})})^- = \mu^-|_{\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})}$.

**Background**: I am trying to prove (or disprove) that if $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are measures on $\mathfrak{L}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\mu|_{\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})} = \lambda|_{\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})}$ implies $\mu = \lambda$.